# if statement is executed while condition is false

Tags: javascript, html, css

On right click on the blue section there will show a div element but if height and width from the cursor to right and bottom end are smaller than 100px, then the div should not shown there. But it is showing.
In the JavaScript `parent.addEventListener` I've created an if statement to do this and provided conditions are false as I also have logged that in the console, whether it is showing false but code inside the if statement got executed.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".parent"),
  child = document.querySelector(".child"),
  listItem = document.querySelectorAll("li"),
  result = document.querySelector(".result");
parent.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
  if ((300 >= (e.offsetX + child.offsetWidth)) && (300 >= (e.offsetY + child.offsetHeight))) {
    child.style.top = (e.offsetY - 10) + "px";
    child.style.left = (e.offsetX - 10) + "px";
    child.style.display = "block";
    console.log(300 > (e.offsetX + child.offsetWidth));
    console.log(300 > (e.offsetY + child.offsetHeight));
  }
  console.log(
    "e.offsetX: " + e.offsetX + "\n" +
    "e.offsetY: " + e.offsetY + "\n" +
    "child.offsetWidth: " + child.offsetWidth + "\n" +
    "child.offsetHeight: " + child.offsetHeight + "\n"
  )
  e.preventDefault();
})
parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  child.style.display = "none";
})
for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  listItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    result.innerText = this.innerText;
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: inherit;
  top: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(128, 161, 51, 0.6);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
  background-color: rgba(128, 161, 51, 0.7);
  margin: 0.25rem 0rem;
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Right click or long press on the blue section, then select any option.</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Me</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Are you testing in multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes I've tried in Mozilla and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the issue here is that your code is checking against an offset of 300, not 100 as described in the question text -- which means it's impossible to trigger a false condition (because the element is 300px square.)

Changing your code to check an offset of 100px instead shows it *mostly* working... but the test for showing the menu also compares against the menu's `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, both of which change to zero when the element is `display:none`, which throws off your calculation.

Finally, you're adding the `offsetHeight` instead of subtracting it as intended (the only reason this appeared to work was when what you were adding was actually zero.)

Here's the result of correcting the math, and using `visibility` instead of `display` to control whether the child is shown (`visibility` keeps the element's original size intact):

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".parent"),
  child = document.querySelector(".child"),
  listItem = document.querySelectorAll("li"),
  result = document.querySelector(".result");
  
parent.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
  if ((100 >= (e.offsetX - child.offsetWidth)) && (100 >= (e.offsetY - child.offsetHeight))) {
    child.style.top = (e.offsetY - 10) + "px";
    child.style.left = (e.offsetX - 10) + "px";
    child.style.visibility = "visible";
    console.log('true')
  } else {
    child.style.visibility = "hidden";  // <-- If you want to make the menu disappear when clicking in an invalid location
    console.log('false')
  }
  e.preventDefault();
})
parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  child.style.display = "none";
})
for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  listItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    result.innerText = this.innerText;
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  visibility: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: inherit;
  top: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(128, 161, 51, 0.6);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
  background-color: rgba(128, 161, 51, 0.7);
  margin: 0.25rem 0rem;
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Right click or long press on the blue section, then select any option.</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Me</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Now, this is perfect using opacity it can be traced on its location but it is hidden now, Thank you .

Comment: On reflection I edited the answer to use `visibility` instead of `opacity`, has the same effect but avoids the risk of any `pointer-events` happening on the child while the element is hidden.

Comment: You may also want to remove the magic numbers from the code altogether; it looks like what you're really trying to do is keep the child within the boundaries of the parent, so something like `if ((e.offsetX < parent.offsetWith - child.offsetWidth) && (e.offsetY < parent.offsetHeight - child.offsetHeight))` would be an improvement.